# How can i make SAML request from .net core console app

Tags: .net-core, saml

Is there a way to make a SAML 2 request using a .net core console application?

My AzureAD has an external SAML endpoint like https: //login.microsoftonline.com/ {TENANTE_ID} / saml2, but I can't find any examples to make this request.

I'm lost please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Microsoft library that does SAML.

Have a look at these [possibilities](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).